# AdMob , ad item in Recycler View hides some items and creates spaces after the ad

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-recyclerview, admob

today I was trying to implement custom ads inside a horizontally oriented recycler view.

Everything went fine, till I ran the app and noticed that some of the items inside my MutableList are not displayed (or are being displayed as blank spaces, don't know for sure) and right after every ad (only does that after ads) there's a huge blank space.

[image: This is what happens]

I don't know what to do to solve this, I'm not familiar with multiple layouts inside an adapter.

Adapter declaration:

```
class CardAdapter (val context2: Context, private val Cards:MutableList<Card>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>()
```

This is my ad holder inside the adapter:

```
 inner class HolderNativeAd(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

    val app_ad_background : ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ad_icon)
    val ad_headline : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ad_headline)
    val ad_description : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ad_description)
    val ad_price : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ad_price)
    val ad_store : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ad_store)
    val call_to_action : CardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ad_call_to_action)
    val ad_advertiser : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ad_advertiser)
    val nativeAdView : NativeAdView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nativeAdView)

    fun createAD(context : Context){
        val adLoader  = AdLoader.Builder(context, context.getString(R.string.native_ad_id_test))
            .forNativeAd { nativeAd ->
                Log.d(TAG, "onNativeAdLoaded: ")
                displayNativeAd(this@HolderNativeAd, nativeAd)
            }.withNativeAdOptions(NativeAdOptions.Builder().build()).build()
        adLoader.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
    }

}
```

onCreateViewHolder

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    val view: View
    if(viewType == VIEW_TYPE_CONTENT){
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context2).inflate(R.layout.item_card, parent, false)
        return HolderCards(view)
    }else{
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context2).inflate(R.layout.native_ad_card, parent, false)
        return HolderNativeAd(view)
    }
}
```

onBindViewHolder

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {

```
    if (getItemViewType(position) == VIEW_TYPE_CONTENT) {
        val model: Card = Cards[position]
        (holder as HolderCards).setCard(model, context2)
    } else if (getItemViewType(position) == VIEW_TYPE_AD) {
        (holder as HolderNativeAd).createAD(context2)

    }
}
```

getItemViewType

```
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    //logic to display Native Ad between content
    if(position != 0) {
        return if (position % 2 == 0) {
            //after 2 items, show native ad
            VIEW_TYPE_AD
        } else {
            VIEW_TYPE_CONTENT
        }
    }
    return VIEW_TYPE_CONTENT
}
```

And getitemCount() returns Cards.size

Cards mutable population:
currenctly I have a SingleValueEventListener which grabs the cards and puts them inside a mutableList calling adapter.NotifyItemInserted() for each item.

displayNativeAd (custom method used in the ad holder)

```
private fun displayNativeAd(holderNativeAd: CardAdapter.HolderNativeAd, nativeAd: NativeAd) {
    /* Get Ad assets from the NativeAd Object  */
    val headline = nativeAd.headline
    val body = nativeAd.body
    val background = nativeAd.icon
    val callToAction = nativeAd.callToAction
    val price = nativeAd.price
    val store = nativeAd.store
    val advertiser = nativeAd.advertiser
    ...
    ... (checks to see if a val is null or not)
    holderNativeAd.nativeAdView.setNativeAd(nativeAd)
 }
```

Comment: Can you show how do you handle the item insertion in the mutable list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All right buckle up because this is a long one! It's actually the "adding ads" part that's complicating things here, not the extra `ViewHolder` type.

You're missing items because you're *replacing* some of them with ads. The total number of items (`itemCount`) in your `Adapter` should be the number of *cards* **plus** the number of *ads* you want to display.

Because you're not handling that, you're effectively skipping over items in `cards` with this code:

```
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    //logic to display Native Ad between content
    if(position != 0) {
        return if (position % 2 == 0) {
            //after 2 items, show native ad
            VIEW_TYPE_AD
        } else {
            VIEW_TYPE_CONTENT
        }
    }
    return VIEW_TYPE_CONTENT
}
```

You have `cards.size` number of items, and instead of showing `cards[2]` you show an ad instead, and `cards[2]` never gets shown. (Also that code shows an ad every **two** items btw, `position % 2` either produces a *0* or *1*, so it loops every second number - you want `position % 3` so it's every multiple of three. But there's more to it than that, we'll get to it!)

---

So you need logic to handle the fact that your *data* (`cards`) and your *contents* (`cards` + ads) are different:

- `itemCount` needs to include the appropriate number of ads
- `getItemViewType` needs to know if `position` holds an *ad* or a *card*
- `onBindViewHolder` needs to be able to translate `position` to the appropriate index in `cards` when displaying a *card*

Let's lay down the rules first - let's say that you want an ad displayed as every third item, that starts after the first two items, and you're happy to end with an ad, to make things simple.

So the *number of ads* is just how many groups of *2* there are - integer division will do that:

`val adCount = cards.size / 2`

The total number of items is that plus the number of cards:

`override fun getItemCount() = cards.size + (cards.size / 2)`

---

Working out whether `position` is a card or an ad is simple enough, it's basically what you already did! Except we need to handle every *third* item as an ad. We also need to account for the zero-based indexing:

```
    |     |     |
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

We get ads on *2, 5 and 8*. We care about finding multiples of *3* (where the modulo operation returns zero) so we can add *1* to each position. This also eliminates the need to check if `position == 0` (that special edge case was a sign your logic wasn't consistent - don't worry I only realised that while writing this!)

`fun isCard(position: Int) = (position + 1) % 3 != 0`

Note that we're using **3** here because we're dealing with the *position in the list* which has been padded out with an ad every *2* places. Every *2* items in `cards` has become *2+1* items in the adapter's content.

Really we should be using a constant, `val ITEMS_PER_AD = 2` and deriving another value from that, `val AD_FREQUENCY = ITEMS_PER_AD + 1`. Avoids *magic numbers* that are hard to read and work with, and easy to mess up. This is clearer (maybe with better names!) and you can just change `ITEMS_PER_AD` to change how many there are, and everything else will adjust along with it

---

Translating from a `position` to a `card` is the last bit. You have to account for when a `position` *isn't* a valid card, i.e. `isCard` is false. It's easiest to return *null* here in that case.

It might help to look at how the translations should work out:

```
position:   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
card index: 0 1 x 2 3 x 4 5 x 6
```

Yep it's one of them logic puzzles - what's the pattern in this progression?

The offset is happening every multiple of *3* items, so what if we divide `position` by *3* and subtract it, removing those offsets?

```
position:   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
pos / 3:    0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 3
card index: 0 1 x 2 3 x 4 5 x 6
```

Nice, that looks good! So now, we need to either return *null* if it's not a card, otherwise fetch the appropriate card from the data set:

```
fun getCardForPosition(position: Int): Card? {
    val offset = position / 3
    return if (isCard(position)) cards[position - offset] else null
}
```

---

Those are the pieces required to size your list properly, work out if a particular `position` is a card or an ad, and fetch the appropriate card from your data. Hopefully you can see how to work that into the `Adapter` methods to work out which `itemViewType` you need, etc.

You could actually just try to `getCardForPosition` in `onBindViewHolder` and if the result is *null*, display an ad (and cast the `ViewHolder` you've been passed to the *ad* one, since that's what you should be getting as they're all using the same functions to determine what's what). Lots of options, the logic around the list is the hard part!

---

As for the spaces, see if it works when you have everything displaying correctly. It might resolve itself, or it might be a layout issue with your *ad* items. Make sure their width isn't `match_parent` or anything. You can always use the `Layout Inspector` with a running app to see exactly what's happening in the layout on the screen, might give you some clues

---

I wanted to check I hadn't missed anything so I wrote a basic implementation if it helps:

```
data class Card(val info: String)

class Adapter(private val cards: List<Card>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    private fun isCard(position: Int) = (position + 1) % AD_FREQUENCY != 0

    private fun getCardForPosition(position: Int): Card? {
        val offset = position / AD_FREQUENCY
        return if (isCard(position)) cards[position - offset] else null
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int) =
        if (isCard(position)) CARD_VIEWTYPE else AD_VIEWTYPE
    

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val binding = ItemViewBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false)
        return if (viewType == AD_VIEWTYPE) MyViewHolder.AdViewHolder(binding)
        else MyViewHolder.CardViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val card = getCardForPosition(position)
        if (card == null) (holder as MyViewHolder.AdViewHolder).binding.textView.text = "AD"
        else (holder as MyViewHolder.CardViewHolder).binding.textView.text = card.info
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = cards.size + (cards.size / ITEMS_PER_AD)

    sealed class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        class AdViewHolder(val binding: ItemViewBinding) : MyViewHolder(binding.root)
        class CardViewHolder(val binding: ItemViewBinding) : MyViewHolder(binding.root)
    }

    companion object {
        const val ITEMS_PER_AD = 3
        const val AD_FREQUENCY = ITEMS_PER_AD + 1
        const val AD_VIEWTYPE = 0
        const val CARD_VIEWTYPE = 1
    }
}

// set up with
recycler.layoutManager =
    LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
recycler.adapter = Adapter(List(32) { Card("Content $it") })
```

Really simple, just uses the same layout for both `ViewHolder`s with a `TextView` in it. Fixed size for the layout, no spaces popping up:

[image: The resulting layout showing the content interspersed with ads]

Hope it helps!

Comment: "Hope it helps"? That's really a complete solution for adding adds to a RecylerView. Nice answer.

Comment: Worked perfectly, the cards are now all displayed and the problem with the extra width after the ad, was indeed for a match_parent instead of wrap_content as you said.
Thanks a lot for all the time you've spent answering my question, really appreciate it!

Comment: @Code-Dani no worries! And thanks @AlexMamo - it's just the basic setup really, but it can be handy for things like adding separator items (like headings) to a `RecyclerView` too

Comment: @cactustictacs  your solution saved me hours, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this works fine, I have similar thing which can help too.

```
class MyVideoAdapter() :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    private val TAG = "AdsCalled"

    companion object {
        const val AD_DISPLAY_FREQUENCY = 3
        const val ITEM_TYPE = 1
        const val AD_TYPE = 0
    }

    private val adItems: MutableList<NativeAd>

    init {
        adItems = ArrayList()
    }

    private var myResult: MyResult? = null
        set(value) {
            field = value
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

    private val itemList get() = myResult?.myVideos?.list?: emptyList()

    class ItemHolder(val binding: ItemSingleVideoBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)
    
    class ItemAdHolder(val binding: ItemSingleVideoAdBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        init {
            with(binding) {
                nativeAdView.iconView = adAppIcon
                nativeAdView.headlineView = adHeadline
                nativeAdView.advertiserView = adAdvertiser
                nativeAdView.priceView = adPrice
                nativeAdView.storeView = adStore
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) =
        if (viewType == AD_TYPE) 
          ItemAdHolder(ItemSingleVideoAdBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater
            .from(parent.context), parent, false)) 
        else 
          ItemHolder(ItemSingleVideoBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater
            .from(parent.context),parent,false))

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
            if (holder.itemViewType == AD_TYPE) {
                val adHolder = holder as ItemAdHolder
                var ad: NativeAd? = null
                if (adItems.size > position / AD_DISPLAY_FREQUENCY) {
                    ad = adItems[position / AD_DISPLAY_FREQUENCY]
                } else {
                    val nativeAdOptions =
                        NativeAdOptions.Builder().setMediaAspectRatio(MediaAspectRatio.LANDSCAPE)
                            .build()
                    val builder = AdLoader.Builder(adHolder.binding.root.context,
                        "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110")
                    val adLoader: AdLoader = builder.forNativeAd { nativeAd ->
                        ad = nativeAd
                        adItems.add(nativeAd)
                    }.withNativeAdOptions(nativeAdOptions)
                        .withAdListener(object : AdListener() {
                            override fun onAdFailedToLoad(p0: LoadAdError) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "onAdFailedToLoad: Failed : ${p0.message}")
                            }
                        })
                        .build()
                    adLoader.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
                }
                ad?.let { nativeAd ->
                    adHolder.binding.run {
                        adHeadline.text = nativeAd.headline
                        adPrice.text = nativeAd.price
                        adStore.text = nativeAd.store
                        adAdvertiser.text = nativeAd.advertiser
                        adAppIcon.setImageDrawable(nativeAd.icon?.drawable)
                        nativeAdView.setNativeAd(nativeAd)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                val index = position - position / AD_DISPLAY_FREQUENCY - 1
                val item= itemList[index]
                val itemHolder = holder as ItemHolder
             
                }
            }
        } 
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = (itemList.size + adItems.size)

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
            if (position % AD_DISPLAY_FREQUENCY == 0)
                AD_TYPE
            else ITEM_TYPE
    }

    fun clearResult() {
        myResult = null
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun setResult(myResult : MyResult) {
        this.myResult = myResult 
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

But the main problem here is, what if the Admob failed to load the ads ?

If there's a condition when ads are not loading from the server at that time:

**adsItem Size = 0**

**itemsList Size = 20 (Assume)**

**AD_DISPLAY_FREQUENCY = 3**

So, after every 2 post an Ad will be displayed, and in getItemViewType method we have the modulas function **(position%AD_FREQ..)**

So. by default it will return the **AD_TYPE** and the **AD** Will not be loaded, resulting in empty **ItemAdHolder layout inflation**. Moreover we will skip the Post Item, as the size of adslist is 0 and we are updating the index for post items, so how to resolve this thing ? I tried checking the adItems size before getting viewType but it's not helping

What I have tried till now is

```
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return if (position == 0) 0 else
            if (position % AD_DISPLAY_FREQUENCY == 0)
                AD_TYPE
            else ITEM_TYPE 
    }
```

```
override fun getItemCount() = if (itemList .isEmpty()) 0 else (itemList .size + adItems.size)
```

In bindViewHolder() for ITEM_TYPE case

```
val index = if (adItems.isNotEmpty()) position - position / AD_DISPLAY_FREQUENCY - 1 else position
```